# Is there any way to make in Gitlab CI/CD a stage with two stages inside?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-delivery

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml file with two stages, and i would like to have that stages inside of a general stage called release. In other words i would like to have stage 1 and 2 inside of release. My .gitlab-ci.yml file is this:

```
 image: google/cloud-sdk:slim

stages: 
  - deploy-website
  - deploy-cloud-function 
 
before_script:
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE
  - gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID

deploy-website:
  stage: deploy-website
  script:
    - gsutil -m rm gs://ahinko.com/**
    - gsutil -m cp -R src/client-side/* gs://ahinko.com
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://ahinko.com
  only: 
    - ci-test

deploy-cloud-function: 
  stage: deploy-cloud-function
  script:
    - gcloud functions deploy send_contact --entry-point=send_contact_form --ingress-settings=all --runtime=python37 --source=src/server-side/cf-send-email/ --trigger-http
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: https://ahinko.com
  only:
    - ci-test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want you just need to use the same stage name like

```
 image: google/cloud-sdk:slim

stages: 
  - release
 
before_script:
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE
  - gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID

deploy-website:
  stage: release
  script:
    - gsutil -m rm gs://ahinko.com/**
    - gsutil -m cp -R src/client-side/* gs://ahinko.com
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://ahinko.com
  only: 
    - ci-test

deploy-cloud-function: 
  stage: release
  script:
    - gcloud functions deploy send_contact --entry-point=send_contact_form --ingress-settings=all --runtime=python37 --source=src/server-side/cf-send-email/ --trigger-http
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: https://ahinko.com
  only:
    - ci-test
```

but if you do it your jobs will start at the same time.
To avoid this behaviour you need to change the jobs to start manually

```
when: manual
```

Comment: Excelent! it solved it! but is there a way to execute the second job if the first one succeed and after a certain time of the succeed ?

Comment: everything is possible, but you have to do it with a shell script in the jobs.